# create a form like MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm trying to create a form where users can type in the title and the content of their message.

layout-wise, i'd like to make it like the form that one sees from MFMailComposeViewController.

how can i make such form? (can i use MFMailComposeViewController without sending an email?)

i'm thinking add textviews into a table, but i'm not sure

thx a lot

Comment: Are you expecting code If so post a screen shot of it so that you can get some help.(As you said (can i use MFMailComposeViewController without sending an email?) so you need it for some other thing what is the feature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a UIView with Labels, TextFields and a TextView to give it almost same look as the view of MFMailComposeViewController and then present the  corresponding ViewController modally using `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`.

Comment: thx, more specifically, my question should be: how should i arrange and configure the labels/textfields/textviews so that they combine and look like the view of MFMailComposeViewController?

Comment: Just look at the MFMailComposeViewController. You can place Labels and Textfields accordingly. There is a separator line between two fields. This can be either generated using a small width UIView to appear as a line or the whole background of the View can be of the light gray color and then there are subviews placed on top of it for every field.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new `UIViewController` in the storyboard and make a *modal* connection to it. Then you can do a *Done* or *Cancel* button on a `UINavigationBar`.